# How to sort an association list (alist)?

Tags: list, sorting

Is there a way to sort an association list? In my case I would like to sort the alist elements by the values in each list element (represented by the integers in the example below).

Example:

```
(setq my-alist '((red . 2) (blue . 1) (yellow . 8) )) ; make an alist

(sort my-alist '<) ; does not work
```

Comment: Make sure you know what you're doing. The element returned by `assq` and friends is the *first* matching element, and therefore changing the order of the list can (potentially, depending on the alist) change the value obtained.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the excellent ergo emacs on hash tables (http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_hash_table.html) I found out this also works for alists:

```
(sort my-alist (lambda (a b) (string< (car a) (car b))))
```

...which sorts by the colors in the example, and consequently:

```
(sort my-alist (lambda (a b) (< (cdr a) (cdr b))))
```

...which sorts by the numbers in the example.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `(< (cdr a) (cdr b))`?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Added to the above. Thanks!

Comment: PS `(cl-sort my-alist #'< :key #'cdr)` is another possibility

Comment: Since this post answers your question, could you please accept your own answer so we can mark the question as done?

Comment: PPS the Emacs 25+ `seq.el` library also permits `(seq-sort-by #'cdr #'< my-alist)`, similarly to the `cl-sort` example above.